# Why do negative array indices make sense?

Tags: programming-languages, arrays, c

I have came across a weird experience in C programming. Consider this code:

```
int main(){
  int array1[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int array2[6] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

  printf("%d\n", array1[-1]);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this, I don't get any errors or warnings. As my lecturer said, the array index `-1` accesses another variable. I'm still confused, why on earth does a programming language have this capability? I mean, why allow negative array indices?

Comment: While this question is motivated with C as concrete programing language, I think it can be understood as a conceptual question that is ontopic here (if barely).

Comment: @Raphael I disagree and believe it should belong on SO, either way this is textbook undefined behavior (referencing memory outside the array) and proper compiler flags should warn about this

Comment: I agree with @ratchetfreak. It seems to be a compiler flaw since valid index range is [0, 5]. Anything that is outside must be a compilation/runtime error. As of in general, [vectors are particular case of functions](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Function#Vectors) whose first element index is up to the user. Since C contract is that elements start at index 0, it is error to access negative elements.

Comment: @Raphael C has two peculiarities over typical languages with arrays that matter here. One is that C has subarrays and refering to element `-1` of a subarray is a perfectly valid way to refer to the element before that array in the larger array. The other is that if the index is invalid, the program is invalid, but in most implementations you'll get silent bad behavior, not an out-of-range error.

Comment: @Gilles If that's the point of the question, this should indeed have been on [SO].

Comment: I use negative array indexes for procedural generated 2d tile maps. If the player moves left the maps generates negative indexes for the 2 dementional map array or if the player move up it adds negative indexes. Right will add positive and so will down.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The array indexing operation `a[i]` gains its meaning from the following features of C

1. The syntax `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`.  Thus it is valid to say `5[a]` to get at the 5th element of `a`.
2. Pointer-arithmetic says that given a pointer `p` and an integer `i`, `p + i`  the pointer `p` advanced by `i * sizeof(*p)` bytes
3. The name of an array `a` very quickly devolves to a pointer to the 0th element of `a`

In effect, array-indexing is a special case of pointer-indexing.  Since a pointer can point to any place inside an array, any arbitrary expression that looks like `p[-1]` is *not* wrong by examination, and so compilers don't (can't) consider all such expressions as errors.

Your example `a[-1]` where `a` is actually the name of an array is actually invalid.  IIRC, it is undefined if there's a meaningful pointer value as the result of the expression `a - 1` where `a` is know to be a pointer to the 0th element of an array.  So, a clever compiler could detect this and flag it as an error.  Other compilers can still be compliant while allowing you to shoot yourself in the foot by giving you a pointer to a random stack slot.

The computer science answer is:

- In C, the `[]` operator is defined on pointers, not arrays.  In particular, it's defined in terms of pointer arithmetic and pointer dereference.
- In C, a pointer is abstractly a tuple `(start, length, offset)` with the condition that `0 <= offset <= length`.  Pointer arithmetic is essentially lifted arithmetic on the offset, with the caveat that if the result of the operation violates the pointer condition, it is an undefined value.  De-referencing a pointer adds an additional constraint that `offset < length`.
- C has a notion of `undefined behaviour` which allows a compiler to concretely represent that tuple as a single number, and *not* have to detect any violations of the pointer condition.  Any program that satisfies the abstract semantics will be safe with the concrete (lossy) semantics.  Anything that violates the abstract semantics can be, without comment, accepted by the compiler and it can do anything it wants to do with it.

Comment: Please try to give a general answer, not one depending on idiosyncrasies of any particular programming language.

Comment: @Raphael, the question was explicitly about C.  I think I addressed the specific question of why a C compiler is allowed to compile a seemingly meaningless expression _within_ the definition of C.

Comment: Questions about C in particular are offtopic here; note my comment on the question.

Comment: I believe the comparitive linguistics aspect of the question is still useful.  I believe I gave a fairly "computer-science" flavoured description of why a specific implementation exhibited a specific concrete semantics.

Answer (score 15):

Arrays are simply laid out as contiguous chunks of memory. An array access such as a[i] is converted to an access to memory location *addressOf*(a)+i. This the code `a[-1]` is perfectly understandable, it simply refers to the address one before the start of the array.

This may seem crazy, but there are many reasons why this is allowed:

- it is expensive to check whether the index i to a[-] is within bounds of the array.
- some programming techniques actually exploit the fact that  `a[-1]` is valid. For instance, if I know that `a` is not actually the start of the array, but a pointer into the middle of the array, then `a[-1]` simply gets the element of the array that is to the left of the pointer.

Comment: In other words, it should probably not be used. Period. What, your name is Donald Knuth and you try to save another 17 instructions? By all means, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I didn't get the idea.  BTW I'll read it again and again until I understand.. :)

Comment: @Raphael: The implementation of the cola object model uses the -1 position to store the vtable: http://piumarta.com/software/cola/objmodel2.pdf. Thus the fields are stored in the positive part of the object and the vtable in the negative. I cannot remember the details, but I think it is to do with consistency.

Comment: @DeZéroToxin: An array is really just a location in memory, with some locations next to it that are logically part of the array. But really, an array is just a pointer.

Comment: @Raphael, if your name is Donald Knuth you'd never even consider invoking [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), no matter it is s(h)aves 17 instructions.

Comment: @vonbrand According to Dave, in some environments the behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: @Raphael, `a[-1]` makes perfect sense for _some_ cases of `a`, in this particular case it is plain illegal (but not caught by the compiler)

Comment: @Raphael Using negative array indices is natural for some data representations.  Consider a SAT solver using two-watched-literals for unit propagation.  You'll need an array of watched literal lists, indexed by the literal to be watched.  The DIMACS CNF spec uses integers to specify literals, negative integers indicate negated literals.  You can use these integers to directly index the watched literals array.  Because the internal and external representations are the same, debugging is much more pleasant, believe me.  You'll have to do bounds checking in any event.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers explain, this is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C. Consider that C was defined (and is mostly used) as a "high level assembler". C's users value it for its uncompromising speed, and checking stuff at runtime is (mostly) out of the question for the sake of sheer performance. Some C constructs that *look* nonsensical for people comming from other languages make perfect sense in C, like this `a[-1]`. Yes, it doesn't *always* make sense (

Comment: I like this answer. Gives a real reason for why this is okay.

Answer (score 3):

One can use such a feature to write memory allocation methods that access memory directly. One such use is to check the previous memory block using a negative array index to determine if the two blocks can be merged. I've used this feature when I develop a non-volatile memory manager.

Answer (score 2):

C is not strongly typed. A standard C compiler wouldn't check array bounds. The other thing is that an array in C is nothing but a contiguous block of memory and indexing starts at 0 so an index of -1 is the location of whatever bit-pattern is before `a[0]`.

Other languages exploit negative indices in a nice way. In Python, `a[-1]` will return the last element, `a[-2]` will return the second-to-last element and so on.

Comment: How do strong typing and array indices relate? Are there languages with a type for naturals where array indices must be naturals?

Comment: @Raphael As far as I know, strong typing means that type errors are caught. An array is a type, IndexOutOfBounds is an error so in a strongly typed language this will be reported, in C this will not. That's what I meant.

Comment: In the languages I know, array indices are of type `int`, so `a[-5]` and, more generally, `int i; ... a[i] = ...;` are correctly typed. Index errors are only detected at runtime. Of course, a clever compiler may detect *some* violations.

Comment: @Raphael I'm talking about the array data type as a whole, not index types. That explains why C does allow users to write a[-5]. Yes, -5 is the correct index type but it's out of bounds and that's an error. There is no mention of compile or runtime type checking in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words:

All variables(including arrays) in C are stored in memory.
Let's say you have 14 bytes of "memory" and you initialize the following:

```
int a=0;
int array1[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Also,consider the size of an int as 2 bytes.
Then,hypothetically, in the first 2 bytes of memory the integer a will be saved.In the next 2 bytes the integer of the first position of the array will be saved(that means array[0]).

Then, when you say array[-1] is like referring to the integer saved in memory that is just before array[0],which in our is,hypothetically, integer a.
In reality, this is not exactly the way that variables are stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
//:Example of negative index:
//:A memory pool with a heap and a stack:

unsigned char memory_pool[64] = {0};

unsigned char* stack = &( memory_pool[ 64 - 1] );
unsigned char* heap  = &( memory_pool[ 0     ] );

int stack_index =    0;
int  heap_index =    0;

//:reserve 4 bytes on stack:
stack_index += 4;

//:reserve 8 bytes on heap:
heap_index  += 8;

//:Read back all reserved memory from stack:
for( int i = 0; i < stack_index; i++ ){
    unsigned char c = stack[ 0 - i ];
    //:do something with c
};;
//:Read back all reserved memory from heap:
for( int i = 0; i < heap_index; i++ ){
    unsigned char c = heap[ 0 + i ];
    //:do something with c
};;
```

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We're looking for answers that come with explanation or a description of the reading.  We're not a coding site, and we don't want answers that are just a block of code.  You might consider whether you can [edit] your answer to provide that kind of information.  Thank you!